# count the key and values?

Tags: java, string

I have 2000 lines of codes,it generated by our DB and the output is like this

```
CREATE UIX:NAME=JSS,RRTE:TTRE,EMAC:TRUE,CHECK:TRUE,YYEE:FALSE
GL0/GL0,RRTE:TTRE,EMAC:TRUE,UWQ:FALSE,ULT:TRUE
GL1/GL0,RRTE:TTRE,EMAC:TRUE,UWQ:FALSE,ULT:TRUE
GL2/GL0,RRTE:TTRE,EMAC:TRUE,UWQ:FALSE,ULT:TRUE
CREATE UIX:NAME=JSS,RRTE:TTRE,EMAC:TRUE,CHECK:FALSE,YYEE:FALSE
GL0/GL0,RRTE:TTRE,EMAC:TRUE,UWQ:FALSE,ULT:TRUE
GL0/GL1,RRTE:TTRE,EMAC:TRUE,UWQ:FALSE,ULT:TRUE
CREATE UIX:NAME=JSS,RRTE:TTRE,EMAC:TRUE,CHECK:FALSE,YYEE:FALSE
GL0/GL0,RRTE:TTRE,EMAC:TRUE,UWQ:FALSE,ULT:TRUE
GL1/GL0,RRTE:TTRE,EMAC:TRUE,UWQ:FALSE,ULT:TRUE
GL2/GL0,RRTE:TTRE,EMAC:TRUE,UWQ:FALSE,ULT:TRUE
GL3/GL0,RRTE:TTRE,EMAC:TRUE,UWQ:FALSE,ULT:TRUE
CREATE UIX:NAME=JSS,RRTE:TTRE,EMAC:TRUE,CHECK:TRUE,YYEE:FALSE
GL0/GL0,RRTE:TTRE,EMAC:TRUE,UWQ:FALSE,ULT:TRUE
GL1/GL0,RRTE:TTRE,EMAC:TRUE,UWQ:FALSE,ULT:TRUE
GL2/GL0,RRTE:TTRE,EMAC:TRUE,UWQ:FALSE,ULT:TRUE
GL3/GL0,RRTE:TTRE,EMAC:TRUE,UWQ:FALSE,ULT:TRUE
GL4/GL0,RRTE:TTRE,EMAC:TRUE,UWQ:FALSE,ULT:TRUE
```

I want to if "CHECK" was false,it will be count GLs for me,also I write the method to read file :

```
public void execToken(File f) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            StringTokenizer strt = new StringTokenizer(line, ";");
            while (strt.hasMoreTokens()) {
                String token = strt.nextToken();
                itemConfig(token, "CREATE UIX:NAME=JSS", poolVector);
            }
        }
    }
```

and it's my itemConfig mehod :

```
public void itemConfig(String token, String condition, Vector<String> vHead) {
        if (token.startsWith(condition)) {
            value = getTokenValue(token);
            String[] content = value.split("[,=]");
            Collections.addAll(vHead, content);
        }
    }
```

any idea?

Thanks a lot ...

Comment: And ideas about what?  What is not working?

Comment: I don't know how can I handle the count of GLs that is under CHECK:FALSE!!! if CHECK:FALSE then count CHECK's GLs

Comment: I think you are going in the right direction, but you are splitting lines based on `;` which I don't even see in the input.  Split on `,` and then on `:` within each of these elements.  You'll end up with an array of arrays (or whatever collection you choose you use) and that will make it easier to find where `CHECK` == `FALSE`.

Comment: Yes I checked it with itemConfig method.

Comment: It's generally preferred to use String.split(":") rather than a StringTokenizer. (String.split returns a String[]).

Comment: @MikeRedford how did it go? you need more help?

Answer (score 0):

```
   public void execToken(File f) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            if(line.indexOf("CHECK:FALSE") > -1) {
               //Do something
            } else if(line.indexOf("CHECK:TRUE") > -1) {

                int i = 0;                   
                while(!(line = br.readLine).startsWith("CREATE"))  {
                    i++;
                }

                //  You have amount of GL's
            }

            StringTokenizer strt = new StringTokenizer(line, ";");
            while (strt.hasMoreTokens()) {
                String token = strt.nextToken();
                itemConfig(token, "CREATE UIX:NAME=JSS", poolVector);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: haha! You're right! I forgot if(line.indexOf("CHECK:FALSE") > -1)! X)

Comment: Was this not an accurate approach? do you want to investigate the problem further?